# Why does my code to capitalize every word in a string not work? (javascript)

Tags: javascript

The below code is supposed to capitalize all the words in a string, but it is not working. The string is split and put back together appropriately except the toUpperCase method is not even working on the first character.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let strArray = str.split('');
  strArray[0].toUpperCase();
  for(let i=1;i<strArray.length;i++){
    if(strArray[i-1]===' '){
      strArray[i].toUpperCase();
    }
  }
  return strArray.join('');
}

let titleStr = titleCase("i'm a little tea pot");
console.log(titleStr);
```

Comment: Strings in JavaScript are immutable. You can't modify them but you can create a modified string and store it in the old variable.

Answer (score 1):

`toUpperCase` do not modifies variable itself, instead it returns a new one, so you need to reassign it.

e.g. this line is doing nothing `strArray[0].toUpperCase();`, cause you forgot to assign it somewhere, same line inside your for-loop.

Working solution based on your code:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let strArray = str.split('');
  strArray[0] = strArray[0].toUpperCase();
  for(let i=1;i<strArray.length;i++){
    if(strArray[i-1]===' '){
      strArray[i] = strArray[i].toUpperCase();
    }
  }
  return strArray.join('');
}

let titleStr = titleCase("i'm a little tea pot");
console.log(titleStr);
```

Comment: I see that it does nothing but I do not understand why. There has to be an assignment somewhere? Thanks

Comment: Yes, `toUpperCase` do not modifies variable itself, instead it returns a new one, so you need to reassign it as you see in code above.